# In modern algebra, what does $(m,n)=1$ mean?

Tags: abstract-algebra

This is modern algebra quiz of division algorithm. What is (m,n)=1 means in the given question.

Comment: The GCD of $m$ and $n$ is equal to $1$.

Comment: $(m,n)$ denotes $\,\gcd(m,n),\ $ so it means $\,m,n\,$ are coprime.

Comment: I usually prefer to write $\gcd(m,n)$. Too many objects in mathematics are denoted by $(m,n)$.

Comment: This notation is anything but "modern".

Answer (score 3):

$(m,n)=\gcd (m,n)$, i.e. the greatest common divisor for the numbers $m$ and $n$.

Since $(m,n)=1$ then there is no number other than $1$ that divides the two numbers at the same time. They are said to be coprime.